# Ошибка AppleAuth Node js - Apple's servers: Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: node.js, auth, apple, jwt, applescript

Помогите плиз разобраться с ошибкой Apple auth на Node js.
вот что возврашает Apple сервер.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "err": "AppleAuth Error - An error occurred while getting response from Apple's servers: Error: Request failed with status code 400"
}
```

это часть файла контроллера registerApple.ts

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import AppleAuth from '../../../../utils/appleAuth';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';


const appleAuth = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    const { token: appleToken } = req.body;

    try {
        const apple = await AppleAuth.accessToken(appleToken);
        const appleData = jwt.decode(apple.id_token);

        // Get appleId
        const { sub: appleId }: any = appleData;

        console.log('appleId>>>', appleId)
```

и сам фаил инициализации AppleAuth

```
import AppleAuth from 'apple-auth';
import fs from 'fs';


// https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens

const config = {
    client_id: 'com.example.example',
    team_id: 'B2222333333',
    redirect_uri: '', // Leave it blank
    key_id: 'FDYEXAMPLE', // ???? https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/add
    scope: 'name email',
};

const appleAuth = new AppleAuth(
    config,
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + `/../static/apple-aith/AuthKey_EXAMPLE.p8`).toString(),
    'text'
);

export default appleAuth;
```

запросы делал через Postman[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

токен получил при помощи физического устройства
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Больше всего нашел информации что проблема с config, а именно с client_id, но он полностью соответствует как и другие данные.
Благодарю за любую помощь или подсказку.

информацию по контроллеру брал [здесь](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-sign-in-with-apple-on-react-native-4c445de5ff8c)